# Android Device connects over adb but not over serial on OSX 10.6.8 mac

Tags: android, macos, serial-port

I have a modified android device with both a adb port and a serial port. I can connect just fine to my imac (runing OSX 10.6.8) using the adb port. However, when trying to connect to the serial port (and run minicom) my mac computer does not see the device, while a linux computer does.

I have tried:

on a terminal on the mac:

`ls /dev/tty.*` (all I see are bluetooth connections)
`ls /dev/cu.*` (same as above)

`sudo dmesg | grep -e tty` (I see no response)
`sudo dmesg | grep -e usb` (same as above)

I've looked in System Profiler and do not see my device is connected

Others have had issues not being able to connect via adb because of an EasyTeather app running. I've check and don't have this software installed.

I have put the device into debug mode via the adb port and tried to see the serial port to no avail.

I literally can unplug from the mac and, not changing anything else plug into the linux machine and see it immediately.

I have power cycled both computer and device...many times.

The android OMAPpedia site gives instructions for minicom (http://omappedia.org/wiki/Android_Build_Minicom) and does not mention connecting with apple computers, so perhaps it's just not doable?

Thanks

Comment: What type of serial interface is this?  Is it a USB-serial device?  If so, what protocol?  Is this a **composite device** with both ADB and USB-serial interfaces on the same USB-port?  If so, there are some known issues with those on OSX.

Comment: This is a usb-serial device. It turns out I was just missing the driver, which I downloaded from here: http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm I am now able to see it in both System Profiler and from the terminal and am able to use minicom. Sorry for not finding this before I posted, but I'm going to leave the post up incase anyone else has this issue.